# Apex Listener(ords) installation to different server

Tags: database, oracle, server, oracle-ords

I have two different servers. One of them includes Oracle db and Apex listener. I want to setup the Apex listener(ords) on a different server. So users cant reach db server directly. How can I configure this installation? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the standard practise. Keep the ords on a separate application server.

On the application server you need the following.

1. Oracle JAVA
2. Application server (if not standalone).  I.e. tomcat or glassfish
3. Port access to the database. I.e. 1521

If you have those you can set it up.